# HLS encryption on Android devices

Tags: android, encryption, http-live-streaming

I trying encryption HLS stream with AES-128. But when I trying to send this encryption hls stream 
to a Android device, but stream doesn't play, but onto IOS and Smarttv my stream working fine. When I debug Android device I figure out that Android check AES key on 17 octet whereas into specification tell us that aes key must 16 octet. I at the end added 1 octet such as 0x00000000, but after decryption it says that this file isn't MPEG-TS.

How could I handle it?
Maybe anyone know something about android hls encryption streaming.

Comment: Can you show the playlist including the Key and IV? The key is not going to be different size, you're probably just misinterpreting the debugging (probably it's a string with a nul byte or something like that.)

Comment: #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://192.168.1.132/key.txt"
#EXTINF:10,
mystream1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
mystream2.ts
#EXTINF:10,
mystream3.ts
#EXTINF:10,
mystream4.ts
#EXTINF:10,
mystream5.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST

Comment: @vigosslive have you resolved the problem. Could you please share your solution? I catch the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the media file happened to be segmented with IIS Transform Manager, you may try left padding the IV fields with zeros to make them 32 characters long (128 bits).

I could get hls videos to play on IOS with shorter IV fields but the video would not play on Android (using the MediaPlayer) without the padding.